# Fields not changing in Formview when moving Pagination

Tags: asp.net, pagination, formview

I have a formview that on page load makes a call to a sql server and retrieves 5 records which I want the formview to paginate though.

I have sucessfully connected to the db, filled a dataset, and returned data when the web page renders. The problem is that when I move to a new page, the data does not change in the databound field.

Here is my code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        conn = new SqlConnection(connstr);
        ds = new DataSet();
        da = new SqlDataAdapter("call to stored proc", conn);

        try

        {
            conn.Open();
            da.Fill(ds, "m");
            FormView1.DataSource = ds;
            FormView1.DataKeyNames = new string[] { "PropKey" };
            FormView1.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Result = ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

Next when the paginate buttons are clicked I have this:

```
protected void FormView1_PageIndexChanging1(object sender, FormViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    FormView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
}
```

Please help,
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to bind the data to the FormView just after setting the new page index like below.

```
protected void FormView1_PageIndexChanging1(object sender, FormViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    FormView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    BindFormViewData();
}
```

This is required because the FormView only displays the data for the active record and does not store any other records from the datasource, so upon change of the page index, the datasource is required to be bound again. See: [Paging in a FormView Web Server Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227443.aspx)

From the above link:

> If the FormView control is bound to a data source control, or to any
>   data structure that implements the ICollection interface (including
>   datasets), the control gets all the records from the data source,
>   displays the record for the current page, and discards the rest. When
>   the user moves to another page, the FormView control repeats the
>   process, displaying a different record.

Hope this helps.

Comment: When I add FormView1.DataBind(); and select the next pagination, the entire formview goes blank like there is no data to be bound.

Comment: Are you specifying the DataSource before calling the DataBind method?

Comment: Does it need to make another trip to the sql server? Do I need to add the full connection string and stored proc, or can it pull it out of the original data set?

Comment: The original DataSet will not be available as the object will be destroyed after the first trip to the server. So as things stand you will need to execute the query again.

Comment: That makes sense. Sorry last question, but is there any way to preserve the original dataset?

Comment: If you wish to cache the data you retrieve for a specified period then you could make use of the SqlDataSource Control. See [Caching Data with the SqlDataSource Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z56y8ksb.aspx)

Comment: I notice you are a new user, If this or any other questions you ask on the site provide the answers you are looking for remember to accept the answers (It rewards posters who give correct answers, gives you reputation points and lets other users find correct answers easily). See the following for more information: [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#5235)