# ASP.NET Formview with paging in nested updatePanels - formview disappears when moving to next page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a page where the user selects a center from a drop-down which will then show center details in an updatePanel. Each center can have one or more schedules defined, so now I want to add a Formview control with paging that will allow the user to flip through the schedules. The schedule will be rendered in a customized table, so controls like gridview, repeater, etc. aren't an option. The Formview code I'm showing below is based on an example I found and is just to get the basics working (it's not the desired end result).

Everything works great on selecting a center; the center details are shown, along with the schedule Formview and the page selectors. The problem is when I click a paging selector to move to another schedule the schedule Formview disappears. If I select another center from the drop-down, the new center details are shown along with the schedule Formview, which is now displaying the record I selected before it disappeared (I should note that right now I'm just using some dummy data for the schedules which is the same for all centers; ultimately the schedule data will be specific to the selected center).

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="drpCenters" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label font-weight-bold">Select Center:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <asp:DropDownList ID="drpCenters" CssClass="form-control input-sm" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="drpCenters_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
    </div>
</div>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="pnlCenter" runat="server" updatemode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div id="divCenter" style="display:none;">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-sm" style="width:auto;">
                <tr>
                    <th style="text-align:right;">Center Name: </th>
                    <td><asp:Label ID="lblCtrName" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th style="text-align:right;">Center Phone: </th>
                    <td><asp:Label ID="lblCtrPhone" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th style="text-align:right;">Center Email: </th>
                    <td><asp:Label ID="lblCtrEmail" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th style="text-align:right;">Center Director: </th>
                    <td><asp:Label ID="lblDirector" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></td>
                </tr>
            </table> 
        </div>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="pnlSchedules" runat="server" updatemode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                *** this disappears when a record is selected from the paging selector
                <asp:FormView ID="fvSchedules" runat="server" AllowPaging="true" datakeynames="ctrID" OnPageIndexChanging="fvSchedules_PageIndexChanging">
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        Schedule
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <HeaderStyle
                            BackColor="DarkBlue"
                            ForeColor="AliceBlue" 
                            BorderColor="DarkOrange" 
                            BorderStyle="None"
                            BorderWidth="2"
                            Font-Size="Medium"
                            Font-Italic="false"
                            Font-Bold="true"
                            Height="35"
                            HorizontalAlign="Center"
                            />
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <b>ID:</b> <i><%# Eval("ctrID") %></i>
                        <br />
                        <b>Center:</b> <i><%# Eval("ctrName") %></i>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <RowStyle 
                        BackColor="DodgerBlue"
                        ForeColor="AliceBlue"
                        />
                    <PagerSettings Mode="NumericFirstLast" FirstPageText="First" LastPageText="Last" />
                    <PagerStyle BackColor="DarkBlue" ForeColor="AliceBlue" />
                </asp:FormView>
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="fvSchedules" EventName="PageIndexChanged" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="drpCenters" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Code behind for Formview paging:

```
protected void fvSchedules_PageIndexChanging(object sender, FormViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    fvSchedules.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    fvSchedules.DataBind();
}
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

The issue seemed to be there was no data getting bound when advancing to the next record which caused the control to disappear. I found

```
protected void fvSchedules_PageIndexChanging(object sender, FormViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("e.NewPageIndex: " + e.NewPageIndex);
    fvSchedules.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    // fvSchedules.DataBind();
}
```

would show me the index being returned and commenting out the databind left the control in place (but of course didn't really do anything). So googling for "Formview paging doesn't advance" brought me to here: [Fields not changing in Formview when moving Pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7463294/fields-not-changing-in-formview-when-moving-pagination) which got me on the right track. Now my code behind looks like this:

```
protected void fvSchedules_PageIndexChanging(object sender, FormViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    fvSchedules.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    GetSchedules(CtrID);
}
```

Where GetSchedules fetches the data and binds to the Formview control. Seems to be working properly so far.